# Rewriting simple permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I am learning about the symmetric and permutations and I have gotten a bit confused about the cyclic notation. From what I read in my lecture book, I would assume that we can rewrite $(12)(13)$ as $(132)$, since
$$
\begin{aligned}
(12)(13)[1]=(12)[3]=3\\
(12)(13)[2]=(12)[2]=1\\
(12)(13)[3]=(12)[1]=2
\end{aligned}
$$
However, Wolfram Alpha has a function called '[permutation cycles](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=permutation%20cycles%20%2812%29%2813%29)' which supposedly can simplify cycles, and it tells me that $(12)(13)=(123)$. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha multiplies permutations left to right. It says so right under the output: "the product $\sigma \tau$ represents the permutation $\tau(\sigma(\cdot))$".

Comment: @DanielArreola, you are right, silly mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Permutations are evaluated from left to right meaning first $(12)$ and then $(13)$. It is exponential notation, not functional:

$$1^{(12)(13)} = 2^{(13)} = 2$$
$$2^{(12)(13)} = 1^{(13)} = 3$$
$$3^{(12)(13)} = 3^{(13)} = 1.$$

Comment: Not always. At least not in _Abstract Algebra, an Introduction_ by Hungerford. But thanks for pointing out that evaluating from left to right is common.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. In my mind this is pretty standard, but I might be wrong.